# WP8 Listpicker dont go full mode

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8, listpicker

I'm developing a windows phone 8.1 silverlight app.

I need to create an ListPicker and open it on Fullscreen mode but always get erros because dont detect ExpansionMode on listpicker element.

My code XML:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    x:Class="FlyGolf_V1.Views.event_detail"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" Loaded="PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded">


    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <Grid x:Name="scheduleGrid" Grid.Row="1" Background="#f3f3f4">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="130" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="80" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="100" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="80" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="100" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="80" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="340" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="340" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <!-- SAVE DATA -->


                <!-- EVENT GERAL INFO -->
                <StackPanel x:Name="datePanel" Height="220" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                            Margin="0,0,0,20" Background="#18a689">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtDate"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                               TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Date" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                               FontSize="25" FontWeight="Bold" />
                </StackPanel>

                <Grid Grid.Row="1" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="130" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row ="0">
                        <Ellipse  x:Name="ellipseStatus" Width="80" Height="80" 
                                  Margin="10,25,10,0" Fill="Green"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="txtType" Margin="0,5,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                   Text="Type" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" 
                                   FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#576A6C"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="txtDurationHeader" Margin="0,2,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                   Text="Duration" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" Foreground="#576A6C"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="txtDescription" Margin="0,0,5,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                   Text="Description" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" Foreground="#576A6C"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="2">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="spStatusComplete" Grid.Row="0" 
                                    Height="40" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtStatusComplete" Margin="0,5,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                       Text="status" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <StackPanel x:Name="spStatusAccepted" Grid.Row="1" 
                                    Height="40" Margin="0,-10,0,0">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtStatusAccepted" Margin="0,5,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                       Text="status" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>

                <!-- INITIAL DATE / TIME INFO -->
                <StackPanel x:Name="initialDateTimePanel" Height="220" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" 
                            Margin="0,20,0,20" Background="#18a689">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="lblinitialDateTime"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                               Text="Initial Date / Initial Time" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                               FontSize="25" FontWeight="Bold" />
                </StackPanel>

                <Grid Grid.Row="3">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <toolkit:DatePicker x:Name="dpInitialDate" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="#676a6c" BorderBrush="#676a6c" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

                    <toolkit:TimePicker x:Name="tpInitialTime" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="#676a6c" BorderBrush="#676a6c" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>

                <!-- FINAL DATE / TIME INFO -->
                <StackPanel x:Name="finalDateTimePanel" Height="220" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" 
                            Margin="0,20,0,20" Background="#18a689">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="lblfinalDateTime" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                               Text="Final Date / Final Time" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                               FontSize="25" FontWeight="Bold" />
                </StackPanel>

                <Grid Grid.Row="5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="41*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="79*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="120*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <toolkit:DatePicker x:Name="dpFinalTime" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="#676a6c" BorderBrush="#676a6c" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="37,14" />

                    <toolkit:TimePicker x:Name="tpFinalTime" Grid.Column="2" Foreground="#676a6c" BorderBrush="#676a6c" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="53,14,52,14" />
                </Grid>

                <!-- DURATION / ACTIVITY TYPE INFO -->
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="6" x:Name="durationPanel" Height="220" Grid.Column="0" 
                            Margin="0,20,0,20" Background="#18a689">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="lblDuration"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                               Text="Duration / Activity Type" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                               FontSize="25" FontWeight="Bold" />
                </StackPanel>

                <Grid Grid.Row="7">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="70" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="200" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="300" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBox x:Name="txtDuration" TextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="#676a6c" BorderBrush="#676a6c" 
                             HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Duration" 
                             VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="250" 
                             GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="txtDuration_LostFocus"/>

                    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
                        <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="lpActivityType" ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly" 
                                            Foreground="#676a6c" BorderBrush="#676a6c" Grid.Column="1" 
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        </toolkit:ListPicker>
                    </ScrollViewer>

                    <TextBox x:Name="txtComments" Grid.Row="2" AcceptsReturn="True" Margin="5" Height="200" 
                             Foreground="#676a6c" BorderBrush="#676a6c" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                             TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Comments" 
                             LostFocus="txtComments_LostFocus" GotFocus="txtComments_GotFocus" />
                </Grid>

            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

My constructor page function:

```
public event_detail()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    String[] listProjects = {
                                "1º Projecto Drive", 
                                "2º Projecto Drive 2º Projecto Drive",
                                "3º Projecto Drive",
                                "4º Projecto Drive",
                                "5º Projecto Drive",
                                "6º Projecto Drive",
                                "7º Projecto Drive",
                                "8º Projecto Drive",
                                "9º Projecto Drive",
                                "10º Projecto Drive",
                                "11º Projecto Drive",
                            };
    foreach (var item in listProjects)
    {
        this.lpActivityType.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

These are the errors:

> Error  1   The property 'ExpansionMode' was not found in type 'ListPicker'.    E:...\event_detail.xaml    123 69  FlyGolf_V1
>   Error   2   The member "ExpansionMode" is not recognized or is not accessible.  E:...\event_detail.xaml    123 69  FlyGolf_V1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add in `toolkit:ListPicker`

```
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListPickerItemTemplate}"
```

and

```
FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListPickerFullModeItemTemplate}"
```

As below

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="lpActivityType" ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly" Foreground="#676a6c" 
                    BorderBrush="#676a6c" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="320" Height="Auto"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListPickerItemTemplate}"
                    FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListPickerFullModeItemTemplate}">
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

And also this as below

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="ListPickerItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="White">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                   FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="Black" FontSize="18" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="ListPickerFullModeItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock Margin="0,2,0,0" Text="{Binding}"
                       FontSize="22" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="Auto"  />
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources
```

After `shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" Loaded="PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded">` and before `<Grid>`

And add in .cs file

```
lpActivityType.ItemsSource = listProjects.ToList();
```

Comment: @Agostinhob07 This answer may help you.

Comment: I continue with this errors:
The member "ExpansionMode" is not recognized or is not accessible. 
The member "FullModeItemTemplate" is not recognized or is not accessible. E:\Hydra iT\FlyGolf\Builds\FlyGolf\FlyGolf_V1\Views\event_detail.xaml 142 21 FlyGolf_V1
Error 3 The property 'ExpansionMode' was not found in type 'ListPicker'. E:\Hydra iT\FlyGolf\Builds\FlyGolf\FlyGolf_V1\Views\event_detail.xaml 138 69 FlyGolf_V1
Error 4 The property 'FullModeItemTemplate' was not found in type 'ListPicker'. E:\Hydra iT\FlyGolf\Builds\FlyGolf\FlyGolf_V1\Views\event_detail.xaml 142 21 FlyGolf_V1

Comment: @Agostinhob07 which `windows phone toolkit` you have use ?

Comment: The problem is solved and yes the problem is the version of windows phone toolkit

Comment: Is my answer useful to you ?